# MVC add token in http header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, http-headers

I have a .NET MVC application which is calling a WCF service. I need to include a JWT token in the HTTP header of the MVC application and decode the token in the WCF application.
The binding is basicHttpBinding. I would appreciate any suggestions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to find a solution and I've sent the token through a SOAP header.

For that I just had to add

```
<headers>
<headerName>Value</headerName>
</headers>
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are inside controller method write :

```
ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("name","value")
```