# Passing Bearer token in HTTP header

Tags: xml, soap, oauth, request, access-token

I have a similar problem to this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780457/mvc-add-token-in-http-header) where I have to send my Authorization token (Bearer token_id) in my soap request header.
This is the beginning of the XML request:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:com="http://target.it/">
   <soap:Header>
      <com:Authentication>Bearer token_id</com:Authentication>
   </soap:Header>
```

This code doesn't work, I've tried different keywords and formats but I always get the following error code:

```
<soapenv:Fault xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soapenv:Code>
      <soapenv:Value>soapenv:Client</soapenv:Value>
   </soapenv:Code>
   <soapenv:Reason>
      <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en">Authentication Failure</soapenv:Text>
   </soapenv:Reason>
   <soapenv:Detail>Required OAuth credentials not provided</soapenv:Detail>
</soapenv:Fault>
```

I'm using SoapUI to do this, and if I add a custom HTTP header through the application's utility it works perfectly, but for my requirement I need to have it through code. [image: The + says "add custom HTTP header"]

Can anybody help me? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think this link will help you.
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLVY3_9.5.0/com.ibm.esoatoolkit.doc/topics/t_esoatoolkit_createsoapUIhttpbasicauth.html

Comment: This is the part that works, the part i need is manually write the header in the SOAP envelope, if it's possible.

Comment: if you want to do with code then simply create a string of SOAP request then send it.Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28342317/add-a-soap-header-in-c-sharp